# Check out stream from AccuRev without workspace or reference tree

Tags: jenkins, version-control, accurev

Since you can not delete a workspace or reference tree in AccuRev (only deactivate it), we want to create local copy of a streams contents, without using those.
I could ofcourse use something like `accurev hist` in combination with `accurev cat`, but that sounds like an awful workaround for such a basic functionality.
So, I wonder, is there an easy command to do this?

I only want to use this in my Jenkins CI environment to check the sources (compile, run tests, etcetera). I never have to push any changes back to AccuRev, so the AccuRev gurus would probably recommend using a reference tree.
However, I want to create these dynamically and they will only be used once.
It does not seem like a good idea to clutter the AccuRev server with thousands of unused reference trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `accurev pop` command to do exactly what you want. Within Jenkins, this is the equivalent of using the option of "Neither" a workspace or reference tree if you are using the AccuRev plug-in for Jenkins.

If you prefer to script this yourself, you can use `accurev pop -R -v <stream-name> -L <some-directory-location> /./` where you substitute in your stream name and the directory location to which you want to write. The `/./` in the command tells AccuRev to populate the depot root directory and `-R` is to recurse the entire contents below that. You can specify another directory below that level using its depot relative path.

Comment: Thanks. Should have investigated the existing plug-in a bit more.
In the help I also found that `-t` can be used to checkout a specific revision.